# Load certain entities only when a player is near

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I have a spigot server with the TrainCarts plugin installed. The trains need to have some chunks around them loaded so they can move and interact with rails, signs etc... Because of the high amount of trains that I have in the map, almost the whole world has to be fully loaded all the time. The problem is that the world has tons of item frames (maybe 5000 of them) and loading them all makes the server run at around 7tps causing a lot of lag and making trains run slow. I can't upgrade the processor because I have my server with a hosting provider.

Is there any way of making item frames only load when a player is near, and not loading them when only trains are near the item frames? Or maybe there is a better solution to do what I'm thinking about?

Comment: They should already only render within 32 blocks or so around the player. Also, this is client lag, it doesn't have much to do with how many chunks are loaded server-side.

Comment: I don't think it's client-side because when doing /gc (essentials) it says there are around 10000 entities loaded and I'm sure that has to include item frames. Maybe there is something I don't fully understand about entity loading.

Comment: How far are you away from the item frames?

Comment: Item frames are everywhere in the map, but I only want to load nearby ones. I also had the idea to load chunks in lazy mode and only load minecarts over that chunks, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Only nearby ones are loaded anyway, client side at least. They don't put that much stress on the server.